# How to set Ruby GEM_HOME and GEM_PATH

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, scripting, environment-variables

**I'm a NOVICE user of Linux and using Linux mint 17.1**

I've reinstalled Linux Mint 20 time in last 3 days for that issue but could not fix it

I'm trying to install ruby on rails using rvm what happened is if start a new Linux installation and try installing gems and ruby and stuff in one terminal session it installed successfully as soon as I close the terminal session I can't get those gems.

By reinstalling it over 20 times in last 3 days I've searched on the web too. I've been told to put environment variable in `/etc/environment` I echoed path in that session and pasted that in `/etc/environment` file.

even now I don't get my installed gems

when I typed `rvm -v` I get the following errors

```
Warning: PATH set to RVM ruby but GEM_HOME and/or GEM_PATH not set, see:
    https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/3212

Warning! PATH is not properly set up, $GEM_HOME is not set,
         usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries,
         it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles',
         to fix temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-2.2.2'.
rvm 1.26.11 (latest) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
```

I'm a very novice person when it comes to working with terminal I can run few basic commands to work with ruby.

I would like to know

1. How to set PATH
2. How to set GEM_HOME
3. How to set GEM_PATH

Below is my full path

```
echo $PATH
/home/sharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin:/home/sharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/bin:/home/sharif/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/sharif/.rvm/bin
```

Comment: mr @mohsen pahlevanzades may I ask what is the point of deleting those two lines, if you dont mind me telling, regards

Comment: If I remember right, You wrote regards or thank you,

Comment: Regarding the edit: [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Answer (score 26):

Sounds like you want the command `export` for setting environment variables:

```
export PATH=$PATH':/path/to/add'
export GEM_HOME=$HOME/.gem
export GEM_PATH=$HOME/.gem
```

That will only take effect for the current session, though. To make them more permanent, add those lines to your `~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 4):

Usually this means that rvm is not setup correctly. The usual mistake is that you didn't modify your `.bashrc` correctly (or similar) or you did not reload your terminal.

You should not set GEM_HOME or GEM_PATH manually when using rvm.

You can try `source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm` and see if that works.

It could also be that you have not built a gemset yet. Do not use rvm and sudo. Rvm works best when installed in your account ant not system wide.

Comment: You can also add `source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm` to your `~/.bashrc` to make sure it is loaded every time you start a new shell.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I learned and how I resolved this seemingly common problem of GEM_HOME and GEM_PATH environment variables not set error.

---

**Background**

RVM install is supposed to create GEM_HOME and GEM_PATH env vars for each RVM that is setup and it does that. But there's a bug apparently such that in some cases the env vars are only set temporarily, and to set them again you have to set them with the command line. I found a workaround to make the env vars persist for an RVM.

**Workaround**

1. **Find your active (in the RVM) Ruby version:** On your production server go to your app directory and type `$rvm list`. This will result in a list of the Ruby versions installed and which one is active for the RVM. Example of the response:

   `rvm rubies
   ruby-1.9.3-p547 [ x86_64 ]
   => ruby-1.9.3-p551 [ x86_64 ]`

So, I know that the RVM is currently using version `ruby-1.9.3-p551`. You need this info for the next step.

2. **Get the paths for GEM_PATH and GEM_HOME**: You do this by executing from the command line `$rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p551`. Then still from the comman line show all the environment settings using the command`env`. Search for GEM_PATH and GEM_HOME and copy those in their entirety to a workspace.

   `GEM_PATH=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global
   GEM_HOME=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551`
3. **Set the GEM_HOME and GEM_PATH environment variables:** Now set these environment variables in one of the many profile files. I wanted to maintain the RVM version isolation structure, so I updated the  /profile.d/appspecific.sh with these two lines:

   `export GEM_PATH=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global
   export GEM_HOME=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551`

Comment: apparently GEM_HOME and GEM_PATH are not specific to RVM?

Comment: @barlop `GEM_HOME` and `GEM_PATH` are used by RubyGems. https://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem-environment

Answer (score 2):

I found that .profile gets loaded last and that puts ~/.local/bin and ~/bin in the front of the path. I moved /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh to ~/.rvm and at the very end of .profile I added "source ~/.rvm/rvm.sh" and the error is gone. I'm on Linux Mint 18.3. I have pyenv, rvm and sdkman installed and they all want to be last. They're all working fine now. :)

If it's a shared system just move rvm.sh somewhere out of the path and any other user can source it, like from /opt/rvm/rvm.sh for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Like @coteyr mentioned, you shouldn't manually set *GEM_HOME* and *GEM_PATH* when using `rvm`. If you check your PATH environment variable, by running `$ echo $PATH` and $HOME/.rvm/bin is part of it, then you need to make sure your terminal runs commands as a login shell. For example if you are on an Ubuntu machine, you open up your terminal then go to: *menu > Edit > Profile Preferences > Command* then select "Run command as a login shell"

This appears to be an old issue with `rvm` which I assume is not trivial to fix since it has been around for a while.

Answer (score 1):

For populating `$GEM_PATH` with my system (Manjaro / Arch) `gems` I added to my `.bashrc`:

```
for _entry in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/*; do
  if [[ -d $_entry ]]; then
    # TODO: Add only if not there already
    export GEM_PATH=$_entry:$GEM_PATH
  fi
done
unset _entry
```